# Pulling historical data with location data via tweepy - python

Tags: python, tweepy

Can anyone tell me why my code is only returning tweets from 2016? I'm trying to get tweets from as far back in time as Twitter will allow. My code is:

```
import tweepy

#INSERT CONSUMER KEY, CONSUMER SECRET, ACCESS KEY, ACCESS SECRET#

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('Consumer key', 'Consumer Secret')
auth.set_access_token('Key', 'Secret')

api = tweepy.API(auth)


results = api.search(geocode="INSERT LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,1km", rpp=100)

for result in results:

    print "ROAD"
    print result.text
    print result.location if hasattr(result, 'location') else "Undefined location"
    print result.created_at
    print result.id_str
    print result.author._json['screen_name']
```

Is there anyway I can pull data for the last 12 months?

Comment: is the first line after `import` suppose to be a comment?

Comment: It's where we put our access token information, but I'll comment it out for now to avoid confusion

Comment: I figured it was representative of some other code but any text that is intended for humans to read but not the computer needs to be put in a comment

Comment: It's best to get into the habit of consulting the documentation, or simply looking to see if a question has been asked, before posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only access recent Tweets for free. *Recent* means *(please comment, if someone has reliable information on this)* something around ~200 latest tweets from the respective area and ~800 for personal timeline queries.

Historical data can be obtained from Twitter upon request and for cash.

- https://gnip.com/historical/
- https://blog.twitter.com/2015/full-archive-search-api

I was buying historical Twitter data from Gnip a few years ago for a research group. You can file requests and the Gnip staff will tell you the price -- however, you cannot just buy data from them; you must tell Twitter what you are going to use it for. Based on that, Twitter decides whether you may obtain data or not.

Comment: Right, all REST API points are accessible. What I was intending is that you can only get recent tweets. I think the regular search has a limit of around 200 tweets, the personal timelines are about 800. Let me edit that.

Comment: Search limit is 200 per request. You can get more than 200 tweets by using the paging mechanism (i.e. by specifying a max id). You can get successive "pages" of tweets to about 1 week in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter only provides free access to tweets going back about a week. You can get more details about what Twitter provides through their API's [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation).